# Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1

Tags: c#, json, json.net

C# codes :

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace BTC_Changex
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double bitcoin_price_dollar = bitcoin_price_method();
        }

        public static double bitcoin_price_method()
        {
            double bitcoin_price = 8500;

            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd");
                req.Method = "GET";
                req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*;q=0.8";
                req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36";
                req.ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
                req.Referer = "";
                req.KeepAlive = true;
                req.Timeout = 25000;
                req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

                CookieContainer cookieJar1 = new CookieContainer();
                req.CookieContainer = cookieJar1;

                HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

                foreach (Cookie cookie in res.Cookies)
                {
                    cookieJar1.Add(new Cookie(cookie.Name.Trim(), cookie.Value.Trim(), "/", cookie.Domain));
                }

                Stream Stream = res.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Stream);
                string reader_str = reader.ReadToEnd();

                var obj = JObject.Parse(reader_str);
                string bitcoin_price_str = ((string)obj["0"]["current_price"]).Trim().Replace(",", "");
                bitcoin_price = double.Parse(bitcoin_price_str);

                reader.Close();
                Stream.Close();
                res.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            return bitcoin_price;
        }
    }
}
```

I have error in this line : `var obj = JObject.Parse(reader_str);`

Error Message :

> Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not
>   an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.

What is the problem & how can i fix it?

---

Edit :
Here is reader_str : https://pastebin.com/fyv7GPVH

Comment: can you share some info about reader_str?

Comment: Here is reader_str : https://pastebin.com/fyv7GPVH

Comment: Also you can open that url in firefox - you will see there is no problem about that json. what is wrong?

Comment: The result its ok i thinkits cause of you are trying to parse array to object.

Comment: Just find the solution I mention both ways using jobjects or object. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON you are receiving is an array of objects and you cant convert it to object.

```
 var objs = JArray.Parse(reader_str).ToObject<List<object>>();
 string bitcoin_price_str = ((string)((objs[0] as JObject)["current_price"])).Trim().Replace(",", "");
```

By default JArray containts list of key value pairs jobjects that you can assign them to c# objects.
Also I suggest you to use **JObject** instead of objects and by converting to string we have access to string index not object.

```
var objs = JArray.Parse(reader_str).ToObject<List<JObject>>();
string bitcoin_price_str = objs[0]["current_price"].ToString().Trim().Replace(",", "");
//or
var objs = JArray.Parse(reader_str).ToObject<List<JObject>>();
string bitcoin_price_str2 = objs[0].GetValue("current_price").ToString().Trim().Replace(",", "");
```

Comment: Hi , i was having same problem as described in question ( json string having arrays) and your answer helped -> i have a list of JObject and iterated over each object in list . But if a key has its value as object as i want to access value of that nested key , how to do that ? would be grateful to any insight

Comment: @Chahat Can you send your JSON and what property you want?

Comment: I found the solution just now.For a nested key like { "abc" : { "name" : "Chahat" }) -> to extract "name value" , I just did used obj["abc.name"] . Thankyou though